# How to open the twitter from android app?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to open a twitter page using a button from a game made in unity.
It should detect if the mobile twitter app is present on the device and if not open in web browser instead.

```
public void OpenTWTR()
{
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            Application.OpenURL($"www.mobile.twitter.com/{TWTR_NAME}");

        #elif UNITY_EDITOR
            Application.OpenURL($"www.twitter.com/{TWTR_NAME}");
        #endif
}
```

Is there a better, more reliable way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that will work for Android -

```
Application.OpenURL("twitter://user?screen_name=[user_name]");
```